# TypeError: string indices must be integers - PYTHON

Tags: python

quando tento listar o json, está retornando o erro:

gravar.append((infos['web_id'],
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Podem me ajudar a entender como isso aconteceu?
Tenho pouca experiencia em python e é basicamente a primeira API que estou estruturando.

```
import requests
import psycopg2

key = 'KEY'
url = 'URL'
head = {'anystring':'KEY'}

r = requests.get(url, auth=('USER',key))

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='DBNAME' user='USER' host='HOST' 
password='PASSWORD'")
insert = "INSERT INTO TABELA (web_id,name) VALUES"

info = r.json()

#print(info)

gravar=[]
for infos in info:
    gravar.append((infos['web_id'],
                   infos['name']
                   ) )        

if len(gravar) >0 :
    cur = conn.cursor()
    y = b','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s)", x) for x in gravar)
    comando = insert + y.decode()
    try:
        cur.execute(comando)
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)

    cur.close()
    print('Carga Completa')
else:
    conn.close()
    print('Nada a Inserir')
```

Comment: Com base no erro creio que ao invés de por o nome do campo como *web_id* você deve por o indice desse campo como 0 para o primeiro atributo dentro do json, 1 para o segundo e assim por diante.

Comment: Oi @LucasDuete, obrigado pela explicação. Carregou o banco de dados, mas com algumas informações que não estão ligadas aquela coluna do json. Você consegue me explicar como identifico o índice de cada campo?

Comment: Abre o json em um editor de texto qualquer ou exibe ele no próprio terminal, ai você olha qual o indice do campo de acordo com aquela lógica: 0 para o primeiro, 1 para o segundo e continua

Comment: @LucasDuete
O retorno que tive:
{'lists': [{'id': '', 'web_id': 'name': , 'contact': {'company': , 'address1': , 'address2': '', 'city': , 'state':, 'zip': , 'country': 'BR', 'phone': ''},
Seguindo a logica eu teria que considerar 1 e 2. Fazendo isso, ele inseriu uma letra na coluna web_id e uma letra na coluna name.

Comment: O problema citado na pergunta parece ter sido corrigido, isto parace ser outra coisa, se os atributos do json possuem um valor e ele está exibibindo outro você terá que rever teu código para ver se não está exibindo errado

Comment: @Maursb de acordo o erro você está tentando acessar elementos de uma lista como se ela fosse um dicionário, seria interessante você complementar a pergunta com uma parte do arquivo json que está obtendo da API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme seu [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/339062/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-python#comment684551_339062), o JSON que você recebe se assemelha a:

```
{
    "lists": [
        {
            "id": "", 
            "web_id": "", 
            "name": "", 
            "contact": {
                "company": "", 
                "address1": "", 
                "address2": "", 
                "city": "", 
                "state":, 
                "zip": "", 
                "country": "BR", 
                "phone": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Considerando o código abaixo

```
info = r.json()

#print(info)

gravar=[]
for infos in info:
    gravar.append((infos['web_id'], infos['name']))
```

Partirei do princípio que `info` seja o JSON supracitado. Desta forma, `info` será um dicionário no Python e quando você percorre um dicionário com o laço `for`, você percorre somente as chaves, não os valores. Isto é, fazer `for infos in info` fará que `infos` seja a *string* `"lists"`. Para acessar uma posição de uma *string* é aceito apenas índices numéricos, mas você utilizou uma *string*, `infos['web_id']`, o que explica o erro obtido.

Assim, como você tenta acessar a chave `web_id`, acredito que você está iterando o objeto errado. Como, no JSON, a chave "lists" refere-se a uma lista de objetos que possuem a chave `web_id`, acredito que seja essa a estrutura que deseja iterar, ficando assim:

```
for infos in info['lists']:
    gravar.append((infos['web_id'], infos['name']))
```

Desta forma, `infos` será um dicionário com as chaves `web_id` e `name`, podendo fazer o que deseja.

Comment: Anderson, muito obrigado pela explicação!